# How to change Django javascript translation catalog string to UTF-8 characters

Tags: django

In Django, when I generate javascript catalog using the default `django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog` view, it creates something like:

```
catalog['Create New...'] = '\u65b0\u898f\u4f5c\u6210...';
...
```

I'd like to change the unicode `'\u65b0\u898f\u4f5c\u6210...'` to the actual characters like

```
 catalog['Create New...'] = '新規作成...';
```

to save more space, because javascript is set to use UTF-8 by default in my HTML page.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I have to change the `javascript_quote` function in `utils/text.py`